# Python (Recursion): "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Just started learning **DS&A** on my own recently and in the Recursion part of the book, it lists the code below as a basic example of Recursion being used to convert an integer into a string:

```
def to_str(n,base):
convert_string = "0123456789ABCDEF"
if n < base:
    return convert_string[n]
else:
    return to_str(n/base,base) + convert_string[n%base]
```

When I call the function and print using `print(to_str(1453,10)),` I get the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the value for n/base in the second return statement is a float. Just explicitly convert it to integer.

```
def to_str(n, base):
    if n < base:
        return convert_string[n]
    else:
        return to_str(int(n/base), base) + convert_string[n%base]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the `/` operator always returns a `float` object, even if the two numbers you're dividing are both integers. If you want integer division, use the `//` operator instead:

```
return to_str(n // base, base) + convert_string[n % base]
```